# clean host name

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have a field in which I ask for desired domain name, now it came to a point that some user includes www.desireddomain on the field. Having this value, the domain registrar API I have will return an error. The approach I have in mind is to omit any characters before period (including period), using preg_replace(). I have a `<select>` which contains (.com,.biz,.org,.net)

```
$desired_domain = "www.desireddomain"; // user input
$will_be = "desireddomain"; // final output after preg_replace() ?
```

And also, does this limits me to only the period or is there anything more I should know? Thanks.

Comment: Do you filter out possible .com's or slashes at the end?

Comment: there's quite a lot they could enter in the form that would be invalid, you need to robustly validate the user input

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to validate domain name in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755144/how-to-validate-domain-name-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use regular expressions since you are aren't doing a "fuzzy" search. Just get everything from the last period on, if there is a period.

```
if ( strrpos('www.domain','.')!==false ) {
    $domain = substr('www.domain',strrpos('www.domain','.')+1);
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to make sure they didn't enter .com,.biz,.org,.net, use explode and do a check.

```
$parts = explode('.', 'www.desireddomain.com.net');
$domain = array_pop($parts);
$invalid_parts = array('com','biz','org','net');
if ( in_array($domain, $invalid_parts) && count($parts)>0 ) {
    $domain = array_pop($parts);
} else {
    // No valid domain submitted
}
```

In this example, they are asking to use "com" as the domain, even though it's no valid. You could create a loop instead, where you continuously pop items off the array until you find a valid part or run out of items.

Comment: Thanks for this, however what if the input is "www.ddmomain.com.net"?

Comment: As per your question, .com/.net/.org are in a drop down, so the domain would be "net", which my example returns. www.ddmomain.com would be the subdomains.

Answer (score 0):

Use the regular expression `/^.*\./`, as in:

```
$desired_domain = "www.desireddomain";
$will_be = preg_replace("/^.*\./","",$desired_domain);
print $will_be; //Outputs "desireddomain"
```

Keep in mind, however, that there are plenty of varieties of invalid data that the user could type in. You are better off telling the user a set of restrictions and then checking them against a regular expression for a valid input.

Comment: What if `$desired_domain = "www.desireddomain.com.net";`, how can I pick the domain name only?

Comment: @boy: you really need to filter out a lot of things- www or HTML at the begining, or say a ';-- ... And if someone pastes in a full URL as well

Comment: For that, you could use `/(^.*?\.|(\..*?){2})/` for the regular expression, but it starts getting tedious after that. The user could put as many `.com`s and `.net`s at the end of that as he or she wants. You could just tell the user to type in only the desired domain and validate it against `/\w+/`.