# PHP Understanding callbacks - difference between preg_replace_callback() and preg_match_all()

Tags: php, callback, preg-match-all, preg-replace-callback

I am a bit confused on the use of `preg_replace_callback()`

I have a `$content` with some URLs inside .

Previously I used

```
 $content = preg_match_all( '/(http[s]?:[^\s]*)/i', $content, $links );


 foreach ($links[1] as $link ) {
            // we have the link. find image , download, replace the content with image
            // echo '</br>LINK : '. $link;
            $url = esc_url_raw( $link );
            $url_name = parse_url($url); 
            $url_name = $description = $url_name['host'];// get rid of http://..
            $url = 'http://somescriptonsite/v1/' .  urlencode($url)   . '?w=' . $width ;
            } 

    return $url;
```

But what I really need is to REPLACE the original URL with my parsed URL...

So I tried the preg_replace_callback:

```
function o99_simple_parse($content){

$content = preg_replace_callback( '/(http[s]?:[^\s]*)/i', 'o99_simple_callback', $content );


return $content;
}
```

and :

```
function o99_simple_callback($url){
    // how to get the URL which is actually the match? and width ??
        $url = esc_url_raw( $link );
        $url_name = parse_url($url); 
        $url_name = $description = $url_name['host'];// get rid of http://..
        $url = 'http://something' .  urlencode($url)   . '?w=' . $width ; 
        return $url; // what i really need to replace 
    }
```

I assumed that the callback will work in a way that EVERY match will call the callback (recursively ?) and get back results , thus allowing for to replace on-the-fly the URLS in $content with the parsed `$url` from `o99_simple_callbac()`.

But another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15650994/php-matching-urls-and-using-preg-replace-callback) here (and especially [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15650994/php-matching-urls-and-using-preg-replace-callback#comment22222625_15651158)) triggered my doubts .

If the `preg_replace_callback()` actually pass the whole array of matches , then what is  actually the difference between what I used previously ( `preg_match_all()` in first example ) and the callback example ?

What am I missing / misunderstanding ??
What would be the correct way of replacing the URLS found in `$content` with the parsed urls ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not pass all matches, but invokes the callback for each match. The callback won't receive a single string parameter, but a list of strings. `$match[0]` is the whole match, and `$match[1]` the first capture group (what's in your regex between the first parens).

So this is how your callback should look:

```
function o99_simple_callback($match){
    $url = $match[1];
    //$url = esc_url_raw( $link );
    $url_name = parse_url($url); 
    $url_name = $description = $url_name['host'];// get rid of http://..
    $url = 'http://something' .  urlencode($url)   . '?w=' . $width ; 
    return $url; // what i really need to replace 
}
```

Please also see the manual examples on [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback)

Comment: Thanks ! that clarify a bit .. I of course read the manual before asking, but somehow I misunderstood the way that the matches are passes. (maybe the examples there are too complex for a newbie like me ) now I think It´s a bit clearer . Thanks again .

Answer (score 4):

The other answers may have been sufficient, but let me give you one more take using a simpler example.

Let's say we have the following data in `$subject`,

```
RECORD Male 1987-11-29 New York
RECORD Female 1987-07-13 Tennessee
RECORD Female 1990-04-14 New York
```

and the following regular expression in `$pattern`,

```
/RECORD (Male|Female) (\d\d\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d) ([\w ]+)/
```

Let's compare three approaches.

### preg_match_all

First, the vanilla `preg_match_all`:

```
preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches);
```

Here's what `$matches` comes out to be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => RECORD Male 1987-11-29 New York
            [1] => RECORD Female 1987-07-13 Tennessee
            [2] => RECORD Female 1990-04-14 New York
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Male
            [1] => Female
            [2] => Female
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1987
            [1] => 1987
            [2] => 1990
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 11
            [1] => 07
            [2] => 04
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 29
            [1] => 13
            [2] => 14
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => New York
            [1] => Tennessee
            [2] => New York
        )

)
```

Whether we're talking about the gender field in my example with the URL field in your example, it's clear that looping through `$matches[1]` iterates through *just* that field:

```
foreach ($matches[1] as $match)
{
    $gender = $match;
    // ...
}
```

However, as you noticed, changes you make to `$matches[1]`, even if you iterated through its subarrays by reference, do *not* reflect in `$subject`, *i.e.* you cannot perform replacements via `preg_match_all`.

### preg_match_all with PREG_SET_ORDER

Before we jump into `preg_replace_callback` though, let's take a look at one of `preg_match_all`'s commonly used flags, `PREG_SET_ORDER`.

```
preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

This outputs something (seemingly) completely different!

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => RECORD Male 1987-11-29 New York
            [1] => Male
            [2] => 1987
            [3] => 11
            [4] => 29
            [5] => New York
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => RECORD Female 1987-07-13 Tennessee
            [1] => Female
            [2] => 1987
            [3] => 07
            [4] => 13
            [5] => Tennessee
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => RECORD Female 1990-04-14 New York
            [1] => Female
            [2] => 1990
            [3] => 04
            [4] => 14
            [5] => New York
        )

)
```

Now, each subarray contains the *set* of capture groups *per match*, as opposed to the set of *matches*, per *capture group*. (In yet other words, this is the transpose of the other array.) If you wanted to play with the gender (or URL) of each match, you'd now have to write this:

```
foreach ($matches as $match)
{
    $gender = $match[1];
    // ...
}
```

### preg_replace_callback

And that's what `preg_replace_callback` is like. It calls the callback for each *set of matches* (that is, including *all its capture groups*, at once), as if you were using the `PREG_SET_ORDER` flag. That is, contrast the way `preg_replace_callback` is used,

```
preg_replace_callback($pattern, $subject, 'my_callback');
function my_callback($matches)
{
    $gender = $match[1];
    // ...
    return $gender;
}
```

to the `PREG_SET_ORDER` example. Note how the two examples iterate through matches in exactly the same way, the only difference being that `preg_replace_callback` gives you an opportunity to return a value for replacement.

Comment: wow . This answer is a great explanation. and it is never too late to teach / learn ,  The only thing is that I had already previously accepted the answer from @mario .. But 1000 thanks for taking the time to explain that !

Comment: No problem at all; didn't expect you to unaccept @mario's answer; I just wanted to finish answering your question from the other thread. Happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

[preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback)

1. Using preg_replace_callback() to Replace Patterns
2. Generating replacement strings with a callback function
3. Generating replacement strings with an anonymous function

Comment: Thanks, +1 although on a java (?) page , those are nice ref.