# PHP- Domains validation separated by comma

Tags: php

How can i validate domains separated by comma, like site.com,site2.com,sub.site3.com which are coming from a textarea
return true or alse in PHP.
thanks

```
if($_POST['domains'] != '')
{
//validation here
}
else
{
$check ="1";
    echo "Error, You didnt enter a domain name!";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a function from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4694816/2765666):

```
// returns true if $domain_name is valid; false otherwise
function is_valid_domain_name($domain_name) {
    return filter_var('abc@' . $domain_name, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) !== false;
}

// make sure $_POST['domains'] exists and isn't empty
if(isset($_POST['domains']) && $_POST['domains'] != '') {

    // split the domains around commas
    $domains = explode(',', $_POST['domains']);

    foreach($domains as $domain) {

        // remove white space from both ends of the string
        $domain = trim($domain);

        // validate the domain; if it fails, output an error but continue with the rest
        if(!is_valid_domain_name($domain)) {
            echo $domain, ' is not a valid domain name!', "\n";
        }
    }
}
else {
    $check = 1;
    echo 'Error, You didn\'t enter a domain name!';
}
```

Comment: that even validated this "ergergeg"

Comment: Hmm.. clearly I should have tested :) You could potentially use `filter_var()`'s email validator and stick 'abc@' on the front of the domain. I'll have a hunt for a better function.

Comment: See my edits using that solution. It's a bit hacky but at least it's accurate.