# Check domain is valid Node.js

Tags: regex, node.js

In Node.js, how can I check if a domain issued by the user is possible and contains allowed characters only?

I do not want to check if the actual domain is existent, only that it is  syntactically correct.

Eg. something.something.something should be allowed, where "*)()-.net shouldn't.

I have tried to use some of the regexs on the question [How to validate domain name in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755144/how-to-validate-domain-name-in-php) however, I'm actually unsure of how to use these in node. They seemed to always come out false.

Comment: regex? what did you try?

Comment: Isn't this the sort of thing regex is used for?

Comment: it is. show what you tryed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like

```
var reg = new RegExp("[^a-z0-9-.]","i");
reg.test("asdasd.com")//returns false, invalid characters not found
reg.test("asd(.com")//returns true ,invalid characters found
```

Comment: Thanks! The problem was actually somewhere else in my program, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The npm package [validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator) would be the best choice and a trustable project:

```
var validator = require('validator');

validator.isURL('google.com', { require_valid_protocol: false }); //=> true
```

```
Package: validator
Weekly Downloads
4,309,787 (today)
```

Comment: validator 13.11.0 is [114kb](https://bundlephobia.com/package/validator@13.11.0) minified ! - if all you need is domain validation