# Delete items from array that are not a domain/link (without http/www)

Tags: php, arrays, preg-match

I am using **php**.

I have these lines of text in  textbox:

```
Technology, Sciene
Domains
www.abc.de
http://cdf.com
something.co.uk

Health, Wellness
Domains
wellness.com
wellbeing.de
feelgood.ca
feelawesome.de.vu
```

My php script is getting each line into an array which I loop through later.
**What I want: delete every line that is not a domain or link.**`

Note: My domains do not necessarily come with a `http` or `www.`

What code I came up with so far:

```
preg_match('|^http(s)?://[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?$|i', $url);
```

I would add an `"http://"` if there is non already and then run the code above...

But it doesn't work.

The Line `"Domain"` still gets recognized as a valid domain.

Any Idea?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755144/how-to-validate-domain-name-in-php

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head:

```
foreach($arrayItem as $item){
     $validUrls[] = filter_var($item, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL); 
}
```

But you could make this suit your purposes perhaps a bit better by looking into filter_var and it's array-friendly counter-part -- as well as some of the alternative filters that aren't picky about http:// or www.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(preg_match('/^(https?:\/\/)?([\w-~]{2,}\.){1,3}(com|uk|de|ca|vu)(\/.*)?$/i',$host[$i])){
  ...
}
```

or:

```
if(preg_match('/^(https?:\/\/)?([\w-~]{2,}\.){1,3}[a-z]{2-13}(\/.*)?$/i',$host[$i])){
  ...
}
```

\w stands for [a-zA-Z0-9_]

See on [Wiki: top level domains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains) what's possible.