# Check valid international URL

Tags: php

I need to check if an international URL is valid. For example:

`http://täst.de/äxample-url/`

How can I do that? I can use any Composer package.

Comment: You could use Zend\Validator\Hostname (http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.validator.hostname.html)

Answer (score -2):

You can try to test the url using a filter from PHP.

Example:

```
    $url = "http://www.w3schools.com";

    if (!filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === false) {
        echo("$url is a valid URL");
    } else {
        echo("$url is not a valid URL");
    }
```

http://www.w3schools.com/php/filter_validate_url.asp
http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it doesn't work with international domains as far as I know. I tried it earlier today.

Comment: Hm okok, sorry. And with this answer?

http://stackoverflow.com/a/4694816/4627253