# Detect if URL has only domain

Tags: php, validation, url

How can we check if URL is only the domain.

```
http://www.google.pl TRUE
http://www.google.pl/aaaaa FALSE
http://www.google.pl/aaaaa?ahaha=22 FALSE
```

I want to check if user only write the domain.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to validate domain name in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755144/how-to-validate-domain-name-in-php)

Comment: you dont need that at all, the server does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

parse_url can turn a URL-string ($url) into an array, but can also return parts of that URL. Using that feature we can reconstruct a URL-string that consists only of a scheme and a host. If this matches with the original URL-string ($url), than it must be a domain-only URL

```
$url = "https://example.com/blabla";
if (parse_url($url, PHP_URL_SCHEME) . '://' . parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST) == $url) {
    echo "host only";
} else {
    echo "more than that";
}
```

Comment: You should add some explanation.

Comment: @Rik , there is a problem. I need have / in the end. example: http://www.example.com/ . How can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: e mean after .com/  how can i make sure that to accept the host only with / in the end?

Comment: You could use trim on your $url. Trim accepts an extra parameter, which is the character to trim. http://php.net/trim

Comment: but in that case it fails validation @RikMeijer

Comment: Another option is to use stripos. First parameter being $url, second being the parse_url url. Check if it returns 0 (with ===). Sorry for my short answers, I am on a phone

Comment: i could fix it. But this doesn't validate if user added .com, .org etc on url.

Comment: @RikMeijer now i have like this: parse_url($url, PHP_URL_SCHEME) . '://' . parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST).'/' == $url.

Answer (score 0):

Use SERVER_NAME.

```
$url =  $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; //Outputs the base url www.example.com
if($url == $mydomain){
   //do something
 }
```