# how to ping to arabic domains and validate url?

Tags: regex, url, ip-address

there is arabic domains on internet like [عربي.امارات](http://%D8%B9%D8%B1%D8%A8%D9%8A.%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%AA)

how to check this domains valid or no in between english domains? or ping this on windows machine?

Comment: Convert the URL into [IDN format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name) and ping it `http://xn--ngbrx4e.xn--mgbaam7a8h/`

Comment: display : Ping request could not find host http://xn--ngbrx4e.xn--mgbaam7a8h/. Please check the name and try again.

Comment: Ping without `http://` and `/`, just `xn--ngbrx4e.xn--mgbaam7a8h`.

Comment: now work but i get "Request timed out." why?

Comment: ICMP can be disabled on the server side.

Comment: Yeah, if you just want to see if the website is up, just use `print_r(get_headers('http://xn--ngbrx4e.xn--mgbaam7a8h/'));`

Comment: or `curl --head xn--ngbrx4e.xn--mgbaam7a8h`

Comment: aha, Thanks,do you exist methods for check format valid arabic domain like english domains?

Comment: [Try this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755144/how-to-validate-domain-name-in-php/4694816#4694816).

Comment: Wow, Thanks Dave! good answer, Thanks Again,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `idn2` tool.

```
(arth@arth ~) > idn2 'عربي.امارات'
xn--ngbrx4e.xn--mgbaam7a8h
(arth@arth ~) > nslookup $(idn2 'عربي.امارات')
Server:         127.0.1.1
Address:        127.0.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   xn--ngbrx4e.xn--mgbaam7a8h
Address: 79.98.120.105

(arth@arth ~) > nmap $(idn2 'عربي.امارات') -p80

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2016-08-26 12:09 +07
Nmap scan report for xn--ngbrx4e.xn--mgbaam7a8h (79.98.120.105)
Host is up (0.23s latency).
rDNS record for 79.98.120.105: web-lb0.web.308th.dubai.aeda.net.ae
PORT   STATE SERVICE
80/tcp open  http

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.88 seconds
```

Comment: Wow, good answer Thanks,